# What's the proper way to edit text in objectlistview

Tags: objectlistview

I have an objectlistview with 4 columns and a dynamic number of rows, I'm struggling with programmable editing a cell text value, and optionally change the forecolor

I've read everything and anything that I could put my hands on, but couldn't find any valid and right to the point example on how to do it.

the ObjectListView is created this why

```
List<VideoItem> list = new List<VideoItem>();
foreach (dynamic item in VideoItems)
{
    list.Add(new VideoItem { Index = (int)item.index, OldName = (string)item.oldname, NewName = (string)item.newname });
}


olv1.AddObjects(list);
```

VideoItem class look like this

```
private class VideoItem
{
    public int Index;
    public string OldName;
    public string NewName;
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Do you really want to start the "cell edit" programmatically? Wouldn't a manual edit (double-click for example) do the trick? What is the exact use case?

Comment: 2. Do you want to change the forecolor of the whole row or of the cell only?

Comment: It's working on dabble click, but i need to programmably edit a cell text on event. I'm doing some logical operations on other cell at the end im storing the result to to cell next to it.

Comment: About the forcolor, i need to change only the cell I've changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i need to programmably edit a cell text on event. I'm doing some logical operations on other cell at the end im storing the result to to cell next to it.

You should be storing the result (making the change) to the underlying model object and then call RefreshObject(myModelObject);

> About the forcolor, i need to change only the cell I've changed

"To change the formatting of an individual cell, you need to set UseCellFormatEvents to true and then listen for FormatCell events."

Take a look [at this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-change-the-colours-of-a-row-or-just-a-cell).

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I really have no idia how to edit the cell

Comment: @Ori: What exactly do you want do? Please describe the exact use case.

Comment: My program gets a list of names, then it processes them according to some logic I've wrote and store the result into the respective column if a file name was determined to be change that respective cell need to be also paint in red. Some time I need to do in cell changes (this is why i need to programmably edit an existing data) the make it easy for my process method.

Comment: Just to be clear. "in cell changes" using ObjectListView are really changes to the model object (VideoItem) and then telling the OLV to update the view. You should never edit some data independently of the model object. That is the whole idea.

Comment: ferder more if the user chooses to uncheck one file i need to clear the result cell and when he chooses to mark it i need to fill it again

Comment: If your logic has determined, that your object is in some state that needs to be indicated (cell red), you should probably "store" this information as a (bool) property of the model. You can then check this property in the FormatCell event to check if a cell should be highlighted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190870/discussion-between-rev1-0-and-ori).

Comment: yes i know that, again the problem is that i don't have a real way to keep track what is the object i need to change the best i can do is find out is coordinate in respective to the listview object i don't store any unique keys about the items that get stored in the VideiItems object

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Rev1.0 Answer, i needed to update the object that contains the items (in my case a List) then, use `olv1.RefreshObject(list);` flow by `olv1.BuildList(true);` 
the `olv1.BuildList(true);` refresh the GUI immediately.

here a small code snippet to make thing bit more clear
it's changing the data in column 3 when a checkbox is checked.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Initializeolv();
        }

        private class VideoItem
        {
            public int Index;
            public string OldName;
            public string NewName;
        }
        private List<VideoItem> list = new List<VideoItem>();
        private void Initializeolv()
        {

            for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new VideoItem { Index = i, OldName = $"old{i}", NewName = $"new{i}" });
            }


            olv1.AddObjects(list);


        }

        private void olv1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
        {
            list[e.Item.Index].NewName = "new200";


            olv1.RefreshObject(list);
            olv1.BuildList(true);


        }

    }
}
```